# Is there a way to automate transfer learning with Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow for building and training several neural networks. These, networks are doing supervised learning on related tasks (Natural language processing).

The common thing between all my neural networks is that they share some of the early layers (some share 2 others more).

I would like be able to share the trained weights of the common layers from one architecture to initialize another architecture.

The way I am doing things at the moment is that I am writing a separate (ad-hoc) piece of code every time I want to transfer the weights. This clutters my project and is time consuming.

Is anyone aware of a method that would allow me to automate the process of weight transfer. Say, for example, to automatically detect the common layers then, initialize the corresponding weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [`tf.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) specifically for the set of variables of interest and you would be able to restore those in another graph, as long as they have the same name. You could use a collection to store those variables and then create the saver for the collection:

```
TRANSFERABLE_VARIABLES = "transferable_variable"
# ...
my_var = tf.get_variable(...)
tf.add_to_collection(TRANSFERABLE_VARIABLES, my_var)
# ...
saver = tf.Saver(tf.get_collection(TRANSFERABLE_VARIABLES), ...)
```

This should allow you to call `save` in one graph and `restore` in the other to transfer the weights.

If you want to avoid writing anything to disk, then I don't think there is anything else but manually copy/paste the values. However, this can also be automated to a fair extent by using a collection and the exact same construction process:

```
model1_graph = create_model1()
model2_graph = create_model2()

with model1_graph.as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Train...
    # Retrieve learned weights
    transferable_weights = sess.run(tf.get_collection(TRANSFERABLE_VARIABLES))

with model2_graph.as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Load weights from the other model
    for var, weight in zip(tf.get_collection(TRANSFERABLE_VARIABLES),
                           transferable_weights):
        var.load(weight, sess)
    # Continue training...
```

Again, this will only work if the construction of the common layers is the same, because the order of the variables in the collection should be the same for both graphs.

**Update:**

If you want to make sure that the restored variables are not used for training you have a few possibilities, although they may all require more changes in your code. A `trainable` variable is just a variable that is included in the collection [`tf.GrapKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys#TRAINABLE_VARIABLES), so you can just say `trainable=False` when you create the transfered variables in in the second graph and the restoration process should work the same. If you want to be more dynamic and do it automatically it is more or less possible, but keep in mind this: the list of variables that must be used for training must be known *before* creating the optimizer, and cannot be changed afterwards (without creating a new optimizer). Knowing this, I don't think there is any solution that doesn't pass through passing a list with the names of the transferable variable from the first graph. E.g.:

```
with model1_graph.as_default():
    transferable_names = [v.name for v in tf.get_collection(TRANSFERABLE_VARIABLES)]
```

Then, in the construction process of the second graph, after the model is defined and just before creating the optimizer you can do something like this:

```
train_vars = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GrapKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
              if v.name not in transferable_names]
# Assuming that `model2_graph` is the current default graph
tf.get_default_graph().clear_collection(tf.GrapKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
for v in train_vars:
    tf.add_to_collection(tf.GrapKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, v)
# Create the optimizer...
```

Another option is not to modify the collection `tf.GrapKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` and instead pass the list of variables you want to be optimized (`train_vars` in the example) as the parameter `var_list` to the [`minimize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#minimize) method of the optimizer. In principle I personally like this less, because I think the contents of the collections should match their semantic purpose (after all, other parts of the code may use the same collection for other purposes), but it depends on the case I guess.

Comment: This seems what I am looking for. I will create a second saver instance specifically for the shared variables. Then, upon restoration, I will just load the corresponding weights.

Comment: I applied your approach. It is fine for reloading. I wonder if it is possible to make the restored variables non-trainable dynamically i.e only if I reload those variables. This would allow not having to change my code when I restore.

Comment: @ryuzakinho I was going to write a comment answering to that but it would be too long or badly explained, so I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you already have some weights saved that you would like to be able to use between different networks.

When initializing a particular network, you could use a shared function which constructs the computation graph through the shared layers, and have a separate function for loading the weights before training.

I often have a module dedicated to constructing the graph, with different functions for building each part, i.e.

```
def build_graph():
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        build_shared_layers()
        build_other_layers()
        build_training_ops()
        return graph
```

The `build_shared_layers()` function would set up the variables and ops which are shared amongst all the networks, but make use of the `trainable=False` flag (I'm assuming you have weights saved for these layers somewhere). You would also provide names for the variables to later reference in a loading function.

Then, prior to training a new network, simply load the weights using a `var_list`. You could make use of the graph collections for this:

```
tf.add_to_collection('var_list', some_var)
tf.add_to_collection('var_list', another_var)
```

Then just grab the collection and have a function that does something like this:

```
def load_existing_weights(sess, path, var_list):
    saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=var_list)
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(path)
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

...
...
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    load_existing_weights(sess, FLAGS.save_path, var_list)
    # get on with the training below...
```

EDIT: Realizing I forgot to add in a documentation link... As indicated in another answer, check out `tf.train.Saver`, specifically the `var_list` argument.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by: "'m assuming you have weights saved for these layers somewhere".