# Tensorflow transfer learning how to load part of layers from one checkpoint file and save all graph vars in another checkpoint file

Tags: tensorflow

When using tensorflow in machine learning, sometimes we want to pre-train a model,and save the model in a pre-train_model floder by checkpoint file (using saver.save()). And then we want use part of pre-train model layer to init a new network , and save the new train model in a new-train_model folder by using checkpoint files.

So, what can I do to implement this function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automate transfer learning with Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569330/is-there-a-way-to-automate-transfer-learning-with-tensorflow)

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow:
When we want saver to save all vars in our train graph, usually we define saver as follows:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

In the init function,

```
__init__(self,
         vat_list=None
        ......
        )
self._var_list = var_list
.......
if self._var_list in None:
    self._var_list = variables._all_saveable_objects()
......
```

If we want to load 2 layers from other cnn model, then we can define a list of variables to restore and feed it to a saver object as follows:

```
variables_to_restore = [var for var in tf.global_variables()
                        if var.name.startswith('conv_1')
                        or var.name.startswith('conv_2')]
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
........
saver.restore(....)
```

It is an example, you can change it according to your own needs.

But after you have used saver.save() to save your new model in a new  model folder, if you want to restore all graph vars the next time, then you can use the code below to initialize your saver object:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

After that, when you execute saver.restore(), you will most likely see errors of the type "tensor node or vars cannot be found".

To resolve these errors, you can do the following when you transfer your model:

```
variables_to_restore = [var for var in tf.global_variables()
                        if var.name.startswith('conv_1')
                        or var.name.startswith('conv_2')]
saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
saver_all = tf.train.Saver()
........
saver.restore(....)
saver = saver_all
......
saver.save(<in new model folder>)
```